# Set user status based on field values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database view which is made up from other views, which has a user and their current level of certification.

The trick is that the user can be carrying older certification from a legacy system and until that expires in a few months, I have to take it into account.

The 3 levels of certification are "beginner", "expert" and "master"

In most cases the user will either have certification from the legacy system or will have achieved some level of certification from the new system, in which case I have their certification level and there is no problem. 
However, there are rare situations which can result in a user having achieved say "expert" from the legacy system but has completed "master" in the new system.
In this event, I want their certification level to be set to "master" as this is the higher of the two.

Any ideas how to achieve this from the view?

The columns are "UserId", "UserFirstName", "UserLastName" and "CertificationLevel"

I've tried case statements, temporary tables and if statements but just cannot seem to get what I need.

The logic is quite simple: If there is more than 1 row for a user, take the highest level of certification and discard the other.

Thanks very much in advance for any suggestions

Comment: How do you determine which level of certification is higher? And post what you have tried, it should make it easier to understand what you're after.

Comment: There are only 3 levels of certification, and they are in the order as above, beginner, expert and then master being the highest

Comment: But you have no column which indicates this order?

Comment: no, the other views determine which is the current level they possess, either from new or legacy system, but I have situations where a user may have 2 rows. All I need to do is take the highest and set that to their level and ignore the other.

Comment: I tried declaring int's such as @MasterLevel and setting this to 3, so I could check if CertificationLevel = 'master' I could then select the highest number but couldn't figure that out either. I appreciate this may be my level of t-sql skills that's causing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach:

You give each level a number and get the max number and decode again from there.

```
select userid, case when max_lvl = 1 then 'beginner'
                    when max_lvl = 2 then 'expert'
                    when max_lvl = 3 then 'master' end as certificationlevel
from
  (select userid, MAX(case when certificationlevel = 'beginner' then 1
                      when certificationlevel = 'expert' then 2
                      when certificationlevel = 'master' then 3 end) as max_lvl
  from test
  group by userid) test;
```

Does this match your need?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/277e6/5

Comment: That works great, but I can't really mess with the table structure. Is there a way to do this with a temp table which can be created when the view runs and dropped afterwards?